# i am unable to get data from current screen to new screen with navigator push after passing the arguments to screen class

Tags: java, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

i have passed the arguments to button in ontap event and now i want to navigate to new screen with the current pressed button data

```
onTap: ()  {
       //toast message showing he selected song title
       // print("${context} You Selected:   " + item.data![index].title);
       Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  SongScreen(title: item.data![index].title)),);
   },
```

now i want to pass that data for stateful widget but i am getting errors i want to bring this data to text field

```
class SongScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SongScreen({super.key, required String title});

  @override
  State<SongScreen> createState() => _SongScreenState();
}

class _SongScreenState extends State<SongScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
         body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              // Below is the code for Linear Gradient.
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue],
                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                end: Alignment.topRight,
            ),
          ),
          child: 
          Center(
            child: Text('data'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => abc(title: "Hello"),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text("Push me"),
          ),
```

```
class abc extends StatefulWidget {
  abc({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  String title;
  @override
  State<abc> createState() => _abcState();
}

class _abcState extends State<abc> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(widget.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```